# Error while importing requests and pyvmomi module in python

Tags: python, import

I tried to import requests in my python scripts but it shows error

```
>>>import requests
```

> ImportError: No module named requests

So I tried to install it using `easy_install`

```
Path\easy_install.exe requests
```

in Windows, but it shows no response and when I run import again, it shows the same error.

Comment: Try `pip install requests`.

Comment: Is it `request` or `requests`?

Comment: @Evert I think she is on windows,  will that command work directly?

Comment: It is `requests`, unless this is some more obscure `request` package.

Comment: @mu無 Yes, it should, if this is any decent Windows command line. But I can't see path settings and such, so it may need the full path, or have `python` in front of it. I think that's mostly dependent on settings.

Comment: it is requests
 and the path is the python path which we set in my computer settings

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have requests and pyvmomi directories located under c:\pythonXXX\Lib\site-packages.

In case of absence, try to install those packages via pip on windows(here you have the [instructions to install pip on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-do-i-install-pip-on-windows)).

Once you have done installation of pip, open the CMD prompt with administrative privilege and use the following commands to install the required python packages :

```
pip install requests pyvmomi
```

Now you could see that the packages are successfully installed.

After this, open the "System Properties" window and select "Advanced" tab and click the button "Environment variables" to set required path variables as shown below :

[image]

> PYTHONHOME - "c:\Python278"
>
> PYTHONPATH - "c:\Python278\Lib"

Edit the system variable Path and append the following :

> %PYTHONHOME%;%PYTHONPATH%;

Finally open idle or python shell and import the packages as follows :

```
import requests
import pyVmomi
```

Now you are able to import with out any problem. **Whenever you import packages, also check the spelling and case sensitive of the name**.

Answer (score 0):

Open cmd.exe that run this command:

`pip install requests`

Another solution is to install Anaconda which is Python distribution that comes with great package manager from here: [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/Downloads)

Anconda python comes with built in `requests` library (and many more useful libraries)